# Convert "Get Raster Properties" output to long

Tags: raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, model

I am building a model in ArcGIS (10.7.1) and I would like to use the maximum value of a raster as the "number of output zones" input to the Slice function. I used the Get Raster Properties tool to extract the max value from my raster but I am confused about how to convert this to a Long variable type (because that's the input variable for number of output zones in the slice function).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought it comes out as a Long and you reference it with inline variable substitution.

If that does not work you can use the model only tool calculate value to convert it to a Long then join that output into the parameter on the slice tool.